# Display only files and folders that are symbolic links in tcsh or bash

Tags: linux, shell, csh, tcsh

Basically I want do the following:

```
ls -l[+someflags]
```

(or by some other means) that will only display files that are symbolic links

so the output would look

```
-rw-r--r--  1 username grp   size date-time    filename -> somedir
-rw-r--r--  1 username grp   size date-time    filename2 -> somsdfsdf
```

etc.

For example,

to show only directories I have an alias:

```
alias  lsd  'ls -l | grep ^d'
```

I wonder how to display only  hidden files or only hidden directories?

I have the following solution, however it doesn't display the output in color :(

```
ls -ltra | grep '\->'
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Find all the symbolic links in a directory:

```
ls -l `find /usr/bin -maxdepth 1 -type l -print`
```

For the listing of hidden files:

```
ls -ald .*
```

Comment: find /usr/bin -type l -print | xargs ls -l doesn't print in color. when I do ls -l it does show colors as I have  alias ls 'ls --color=auto'

Comment: There is a little problem. If there is no symlinks under /usr/bin, the comamnd equals to ls -l, means to display current directory without filter.

Answer (score 13):

For only "hidden" folders - dot folders, try:

```
ls -l .**
```

Yes, the two asterisks are necessary, otherwise you'll also get . and .. in the results.

For symlinks, well, try the symlinks program:

```
symlinks -v .
```

(shows all symlinks under current directory)

Comment: In what shell does the expansion of `.**` exclude `.` and `..`? In bash, it's equivalent to `.*`, and it includes `.` and `..`. In zsh, both `.*` and `.**` *exclude* `.` and `..`.

Comment: "symlinks -v" worked perfect for me, nevertheless, I had to specify the directory, it doesn't work implicitly in the current directory, you have to specify it.

Answer (score 12):

```
ls -l | grep lrw
```

shows only symlinks (files and directories). Not sure how to get them colorful, though.

```
ls -lad .*
```

shows only hidden files/directories

```
ls -l | grep drw
```

shows directories only.

Answer (score 8):

To display JUST the symlinks and what they link to:

```
find -P . -type l -exec echo -n "{} -> " \; -exec readlink {} \;
```

To limit to JUST THIS DIR

```
find -P .  -maxdepth 1 -type l -exec echo -n "{} -> " \; -exec readlink {} \;
```

Example output (after ln -s /usr/bin moo):

```
./moo -> /usr/bin
```

Answer (score 6):

You were almost there with your grep solution; let's focus on getting you COLOR again.

Try this:

```
ls --color=always -ltra | grep '->'
```

Comment: Clever. I needed to escape the dash in the grep statement: grep '\->'

Comment: @JesseFisher: Or `grep -e '->'`

Answer (score 5):

Improving a little on the accepted answer given by @ChristopheD (coudnt comment on the accepted answer since I dont have enough reputation)

I use an alias

```
findsymlinks <path> <depth>
```

where the alias is

```
alias findsymlinks "find \!:1 -maxdepth \!:2 -type l -print | xargs ls -l --color=auto"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try file type flag and get rid of the appending @

```
ls -F /home/usr/foo | grep "@" | sed 's/@//'
```

Answer (score 1):

**For (t)csh**:

```
ls --color=always -ltra | grep '\->'
```

(This is simply [pbr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1479762/1556416) but with the hyphen escaped.)

**Mac OSX**

On OSX, `ls` works differently, so add this to your `~/.cshrc` file:

```
setenv CLICOLOR_FORCE 1   # (equivalent of Linux --color=always)
```

And then call:

```
ls -G -ltra | grep '\->'  # (-G is equivalent of ls --color)
```

Answer (score 1):

**For bash:**
*This provides a nice output.*

```
sl=`find -L /path/to/target -xtype l`; for links in $sl; do ls --color=always -ltra $links; done | sed 's/^/    /'
```

Answer (score -1):

Usage: foo $path

Uses current path if none specified.

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in

    -r)
    find $2 -type l -print | while IFS= read line ; do ls -l --color=always "$line"; done
    ;;

    --help)
    echo 'Usage: foo [-r] [$PATH]'
    echo    
    echo '-r  Recursive'
    ;;


    *)
    ls --color=always -ltra $1 | grep '\->'
esac
```