# Weird recursive directory structure

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Somehow, my system (Ubuntu WSL layer on Windows; so treat as exactly Ubuntu) went a bit crazy. For a directory (a git repo if it matters) `/path/to/foo`, running `ls` shows the git files `ORIG_HEAD`, `index`, and `index.lock` in there.

I tried to debug this by going `cd .git`, but an `ls` there showed me my same list of files as the parent!

I went as far as

`/path/to/foo/.git/.git/.git`

before stopping checking the recursion.

A possibly related issue that managed to show up is that the `.htaccess` file there is read as a file by Emacs on Windows, a file by `vi` on Linux, but a directory by `emacs` and a directory by bash.

That means that my computer really thinks

`~/public_html/.git/.htaccess/.htaccess/.git/.htaccess/.git/.git`

is identical to

`~/public_html`

So, needless to say, Apache also craps out and says that it's an invalid htaccess file .... though on an other machine (see: git repo) it runs just fine.

Help?

Comment: Looks like `.git` is a symbolic link to the current directory: `ln -s . .git` You can see something similar in, for example, http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu/

Comment: @muru but then shouldn't `rm .git` work? I get the standard `Is a directory` error.  Similarly, via [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1412554/1877527), `symlinks -v .` shows nothing. I'd also then expect `rm .htaccess && git checkout -- .htaccess` to fix links to the file, which also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried nuking the directory via `rm -rf` and `git clone`-ing back, but the Apache problem persisted.

I removed the symlink to the directory via `unlink`:

```
~$ unlink public_html
```

then re-mounted it, making sure that there wasn't a trailing space

```
~$ ln -s /mnt/c/Users/USER/pathto/repo /home/USER/public_html
```